# Extracting Attribute Value from HTML using HtmlUnit / XPath?

Tags: html, parsing, xpath, htmlunit

I am using HtmlUnit to parse through a website's source code and extracting camera titles. The website contains several different cameras and I need to somehow create a list of all the camera titles. Below is one example of one of the cameras in the source code (I changed the camera title to make it cleaner):

```
<a href="/camera/p-SPM7903509713?prdNo=2" title="Camera Title" onclick="javascript:appendOmParams(this, 'SPM7903509713');">Camera Title</a>
```

I am assuming I need to use XPath, which I just discovered, since HtmlUnit doesn't have a built in function along the lines of getElementsByTitle(). How might I do this with the above example? My attempt is this:

```
final List<?> titles = webPage.getByXPath("//a[@title=*]");
```

However this does not work. The logic is to say, as long as "a" has the attribute "title" it doesn't matter what the title is, I want it, hence the asterisk. Anyone know how I might approach this?

Answer (score 2):

You've been very close to the correct expression. Use `//a[@title]` to find all links having a title attribute. Predicates evaluate to true if they return something (are not empty), and `@title` will select all title attributes within the current tag.

If you would want to retrieve all titles, you would go for `//a/@title`.